# When does Android broadcast ACTION_DATE_CHANGED?

Tags: android, android-broadcast

I am designing an alarm clock app, and I need to listen to two system broadcasts: [`Intent.ACTION_TIME_CHANGED`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent#ACTION_TIME_CHANGED) and [`Intent.ACTION_DATE_CHANGED`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent#ACTION_DATE_CHANGED).

I believe `ACTION_TIME_CHANGED` is fired when the user manually changes the time. But when is `ACTION_DATE_CHANGED` broadcasted?

The documentation of this action is not quite convincing. It says,

> The date has changed.

Who changed the date? The user, by changing the date setting? Or did the clock tick over to the next day?

Two Stack Overflow answers that I found regarding this:

- [Answer 1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21980497/8387076): The broadcast is fired when the clock ticks over to the next day.
- [Answer 2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19112483/8387076): The broadcast is fired when the user manually changes the date, and is not automatically triggered by the system.

The two answers indicate completely different behaviour. If answer #1 is correct, I will listen to this broadcast using a context-registered receiver. If answer #2 is correct, I need to register a context-registered receiver for `Intent.ACTION_TIME_TICK` and then manually check whether we are in the next day or the same day.

Comment: How about you test both? It shouldn't be too hard.

Comment: I was thinking about that. Will do so and publish the results soon. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the suggestion by @Nicolas, I tested both the broadcasts. The results:

- `ACTION_TIME_CHANGED` is broadcasted only when the user manually changes the date, time or time format (from 12-hour to 24-hour format or vice-versa).
- `ACTION_DATE_CHANGED` is broadcasted only when the day changes, i.e. when we go from 11:59 PM to 12:00 AM of the next day. This is automatically triggered by the system.

Comment: One thing to note that now these broadcast may or may not fire when system in DOZE mode. :)

Comment: Not only that, [another SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16684132/8387076) has pointed out that if the device has "Use network provided date and time" enabled, then `ACTION_TIME_CHANGED` and `ACTION_TIMEZONE_CHANGED` may be fired even when the user has not manually changed the date and/or time.

Comment: There is a bug regarding `ACTION_DATE_CHANGED` so it does not always fire up when clock goes from 23:59 to 00:00, nor does it always fire when you change the date manually. It is not reliable at all. [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21758246/android-action-date-changed-broadcast/21980389)